# What is Entity in android?

Tags: android, encryption

I'm beginner in android.I'm using below code(Facebook Conceal Library) for encrypt and decrypt video but I dont't know what is Entity exactly?I searched many time on the net and also visited [developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Entity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Entity) but I don't know what should I use for Entity still?

```
public void testEncrypt()
{
    File inputFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/video1.mp4");
    try {
        final byte[] encrypt = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("/storage/emulated/0/Download/", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath = new File(directory, "encrypt.mp4");

        Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this), new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

        if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        OutputStream fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(mypath));
        OutputStream outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                fileStream, new **Entity()**);
        outputStream.write(encrypt);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Encrypted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public Void testDecrypt() {
    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this),
            new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("/storage/emulated/0/Download/", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(directory, "decrypt.mp4");

    try {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(fileStream,
                new **Entity()**);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Decrypted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: That Android class is not the right one. The correct [`Entity` class](https://github.com/facebook/conceal/blob/master/java/com/facebook/crypto/Entity.java) is in the library, and [the README](https://github.com/facebook/conceal/blob/master/README.md) explains exactly what it is, and how to use it, with examples, in the section labelled __Usage__ -> __Entity and keys__.

Comment: @MikeM.Oh you are right.Thanks a lot

Comment: @MikeM.Did you use this library?Do you know better library?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I just opened your question because I was curious as to how you were using Android's `Entity` class. Turns out, it wasn't that class at all. :-)